# How to Accurately Count and Time Movement Events in Sensor Data with Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on a Python project involving sensor data analysis, specifically using accelerometer and gyroscope readings (2 sensors) from a CSV file (3gb).

The goal is to identify movement events based on certain conditions (e.g., accVector1 > 1 OR accVector2> 1 OR gyroVector1> 50 OR  gyroVector2> 50 ), count these events, and further categorize them based on their duration and periodicity.

**The Conditions Are:**

1. A movement event starts when *accVector1 > 1 OR accVector2> 1 OR gyroVector1> 50 OR  gyroVector2> 50*.
2. The event's duration must be between 1 and 10 seconds to be considered valid.
3. If more than 90 seconds pass without any movement event, the lm_counter should reset
4. I need to count these valid events (movement_counter), total movements (total_LM), and identify when four consecutive valid events occur (periodic_counter , movement_counter should be reseted when the periodic_counter incresed).

---

for example

- *accVector1 > 1 condition is met* --> if this condition takes 1 - 10 seconds, increas movement_counter, otherwise nothing. ( but the program shouldn't confuse "OR" statement when accVector1 > 1 is met, we need to continue with accVector1 movement time by not interrupting with other conditions)
- At the same time, check the time when other condition met. If this time is greater than 90, make the movement_counter=0
- *When the movement_counter=4*, increases the periodic_counter as +1 and makes movement_counter=0 again.

for each row in the CSV file;

```
    if accVector1>1 or accVector2>1 or gyroVector1>50 or gyroVector2>50:
        if not movement_start:
            movement_start = current_time
    else:
        if movement_start:
            movement_duration = (current_time - movement_start)            
            if 0.5 < movement_duration < 10:
                movement_counter += 1
                total_LM+=1
                hareketin_bitisi = current_time
                movement_start = None
                if movement_counter == 4:
                    movement_counter = 0
                    periodic_movement += 1
            else:
                movement_start = None
    if hareketin_bitisi and (current_time - hareketin_bitisi) > 90:
        movement_counter = 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What do you need help with? Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This looks like it could be an interesting problem, but we need some help from you. You've said what your goal is, but haven't pointed to a specific problem or issue you're having. You've also given some code, but what your audience could really use is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which would allow others to see and work on the problem first-hand. Please edit your question to add these elements.